# Change the "Quantity" text in the woocommerce cart page when 2 products from different categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So i'll try to be as specific as possible,
I have 2 different categories on my woocommerce, each category has a different label:

1.Instead of "quantity" -> "LABEL1".

2.Instead of "quantity" -> "LABEL2".

I've done this by modifying the quantity-input.php :

```
if (is_page('cart') || is_cart()) {
            // If it's the cart page do this
            foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
                // If Cart has category "CATEGORYNAME" do this
                if (has_term('CATEGORYNAME', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'])) {
                    esc_html_e('LABEL1', 'woocommerce');
                } else {
                    esc_html_e('LABEL2', 'woocommerce');
                }
            }
        }
```

So this works when the clients only adds products from one category , but when he adds a product from the other category i get LABEL1LABEL2.

Shouldn't the foreach loop , loop for through the categories and give me a different label?

I've been searching but i can't find a solution for this specific thing.

Comment: Do you just need to return labels based on category wise ?

Comment: Yes! there are multiple categories , but only 1 of them has a different label.

Answer (score 1):

Alright i fixed this , i was wrong trying to loop in the quantity-input.php file ,

I fixed it by modifying the cart.php . Here is what i did:

```
echo apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item);
```

//Add this after this line:

```
if ($_product->get_category_ids()[0] == 99) {
                    echo '<div>';
                    esc_html_e('LABEL1', 'woocommerce');
                    echo '</div>';
                } else {
                    echo '<div>';
                    esc_html_e('LABEL2', 'woocommerce');
                    echo '</div>';
                }
```

Thanks for the help!